# close current div and open another

Tags: javascript

I'm hours I feel.
I can not tell my script when I press a button must close the display before opening the new one , someone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.testoprodotto').addClass("hidden");

    $('.testoprodotto').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible"); // Dropdown
            $(this).find('.more').hide().siblings('.less').show(); // Button
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden"); // Dropdown
            $(this).find('.more').show().siblings('.less').hide(); // Button
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/divieto/uvz2ngsk/

Comment: Question is not really clear... What do you want? When you click on a div (you want it to show), you want all already opened divs to hide?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to call the click on the one that is visible.

```
$('.testoprodotto').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
        $('.testoprodotto.visible').click();
        $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");  
        /* rest of your code */
```

Comment: There is a show/hide function in jQuery, like toggle too... :) no real need to add/remove classes...

Comment: And that should be a comment to OP above and with classes it makes it possible to do other things with CSS unlike show/hide which just adds display inline.